Problema con Width y body
Me dieron un ejercicio donde me piden que el body tenga 1600 px de width. Se que esto es muy mala práctica pero es lo que quiere el docente. La confusión surge por que esto me está generando un scroll horizontal que no entienedo por que aparece. Entiendo que no debería suceder ya que mi resolución es de 1920 x 1080 por lo que los 1600 de width deberían entrar. Si borro esa linea el scroll desaparece así que es eso lo que lo está causando.
Probé sacando el border box pero el problema persiste.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barra de Navegación</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      
  
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Primario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secundario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autoridades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
    
        <img class="imagen" src="images/aulavirtual.jpg" alt="Descripción de la imagen">
    
      
        <p>Este es un ejemplo de estructura básica de HTML y CSS.</p>
    </main>

    <aside>
        <h2>Barra Lateral</h2>
        <p>Contenido adicional como enlaces o widgets.</p>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2024 Mi Sitio Web. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>

CSS
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
 
 #imagen-copello{

width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
} 


/* 1. Configuración del cuerpo */
body {
    background-color:lightblue; /* Color de fondo celeste */
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; /* Fuente predeterminada */
    /* Ancho */
    margin: 0; /* Margen de 0 */

  
}

/* 2. Estilo de la barra de navegación */
.navbar {
    background-color: #0000FF; /* Color de fondo azul */
    height: 60px; /* Altura */
    

}

/* 3. Estilo del menú de la barra de navegación */
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Sin viñetas en los ítems */
    margin: 0; /* Margen de 0 */
    padding: 0; /* Padding de 0 */
  width: 1600px;
}

.navbar li {
    
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
}

.navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;     /* Sin subrayado */
    color: white;             /* Color blanco */
    font-size: 22px;         /* Tamaño de fuente de 22px */
    display: block;          /* Display bloqueado */
    line-height: 50px;       /* Altura de línea de 50px */
}

.imagen {
width: 250px;
}


h1{
   
    font-size: 46px;
}



La resolución no es el único factor que influye para determinar la cantidad de pixeles disponibles. También está la escala (o el zoom)
1) Zoom de los navegadores
Los navegadores tienen un zoom que modifica la cantidad de pixeles disponibles, está opción está disponible desde el menú o ctrl+rueda_mouse
Por ejemplo, ejecuta el siguiente código y cambia el zoom, podrá notar como la cantidad de pixeles disponibles cambia


new ResizeObserver(() =>console.log('Width : ', document.body.clientWidth)).observe(document.body); 



2) Escala en Windows
En Windows 11 (desconozco si se da en otras versiones o en otros SO) cuenta con la opción de escalar la resolución.
En configuración > Sistema > Pantalla, se encuentra la "escala"

Yo en mi computadora tengo una resolución de 3840 x 2400, pero escalado al 200%, lo que provoca que las páginas web tenga un máximo de 1920px de ancho
Como anécdota: Hace unos años tuve un problema con unos clientes y con bootstrap (no recuerdo que versión). El caso, es que en las computadoras de mis clientes veían el sistema en versión tablet (no en escritorio como debería haber sido), y después de mucho dar vueltas, el problema era justamente la escala con que venían seteado windows en esos computadores

Era el escalado. Díos mío cuantas minucias a tener en cuenta. me estaba volvliendo loco sin encontrar la causa.  Todos los días se aprende algo nuevo! saludos.

Estás a un paso, solo necesitas agregar:
 /* agregamos la disposición */
html {
    display: flex;
}

body {
    background-color:lightblue; /* Color de fondo celeste */
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; /* Fuente predeterminada */
     /* modificamos el margen */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Margen de 0 */ 
     //* determinamos el ancho */
    width : "1600px";
}



<! CSS >

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
#imagen-copello {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
} 

html {
    display: flex;
}

/* 1. Configuración del cuerpo */
body {
    background-color:lightblue; /* Color de fondo celeste */
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; /* Fuente predeterminada */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Margen de 0 */ 
     /* Ancho */
    width : "1600px";
}

/* 2. Estilo de la barra de navegación */
.navbar {
    background-color: #0000FF; /* Color de fondo azul */
    height: 60px; /* Altura */
}

/* 3. Estilo del menú de la barra de navegación */
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Sin viñetas en los ítems */
    margin: 0; /* Margen de 0 */
    padding: 0; /* Padding de 0 */
  width: 1600px;
}

.navbar li {    
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
}

.navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;     /* Sin subrayado */
    color: white;             /* Color blanco */
    font-size: 22px;         /* Tamaño de fuente de 22px */
    display: block;          /* Display bloqueado */
    line-height: 50px;       /* Altura de línea de 50px */
}

.imagen {
    width: 250px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 46px;
}
<! HTML > 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barra de Navegación</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>  
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Primario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secundario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autoridades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>    
        <img class="imagen" src="images/aulavirtual.jpg" alt="Descripción de la imagen">      
        <p>Este es un ejemplo de estructura básica de HTML y CSS.</p>
    </main>

    <aside>
        <h2>Barra Lateral</h2>
        <p>Contenido adicional como enlaces o widgets.</p>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2024 Mi Sitio Web. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>




gracias por la respuesta pero estaba interesado en saber la causa del problema la cuál fue clarificada en el comentario anterior. Saludos!
